# Is there a socketio client to connect to the supported message brokers in python-socketio?

Tags: python-socketio

I guess I was looking for one all be all python socketio module. Then as I start to use the message broker with socketio, the documentation demonstrated well, using redis. However, I find it odd that python-socketio client didn't show how to connect to a message broker. Is that the intent and to leave it to the followers of the project?

I had to rely on just the python redis to see how python-socketio connects to the redis, provided that it's given the db with the address. Further more, I found socket.io to the be default channel of it all and emitting more information than I expected.

Expected: {'foo':'bar'}

Observed: {'method': 'emit', 'event': 'event', 'data': {'foo': 'bar'}, 'namespace': '/learning_it', 'room': None, 'skip_sid': None, 'callback': None, 'host_id': ''}

From this point of the module usage, are we to operate as we please?

Thank you Miguel Grinberg,
from a Fan.

Answer (score 12):

You are misunderstanding the role of the message queue.

Let's forget about the queue for a moment. We have one or more clients and just one server. The clients connect to the server, either through long-polling or websocket. I assume this is all clear.

```
client1 ---+
           |
client2 ---+--- server
           |
client3 ---+
```

Now let's say you want to scale your server because you have too many clients, so many that your single server cannot handle them all.

The solution is to run multiple servers, all behind a load balancer:

```
client1 ---+                     +--- server1
           |                     |
client2 ---+--- load balancer ---+
           |                     |
client3 ---+                     +--- server2
```

So far so good? The problem with this solution is that each of the servers knows only about a subset of the clients, so there is no way to broadcast an event to all clients. It's not even possible to send an event to a room, since the participants in that room are likely going to be randomly assigned to different servers.

So how did I solve this problem? I added a message queue, that all the servers use to coordinate broadcasts:

```
client1 ---+                     +--- server1 ---+
           |                     |               |
client2 ---+--- load balancer ---+               +--- pub/sub queue
           |                     |               |
client3 ---+                     +--- server2 ---+
```

With this design, a server can issue a broadcast by sending the event to the subset of the clients it knows about, and then asking the other servers to do the same by publishing a request on the queue.

The payloads that you are seeing on your Redis server are internal and meant to be consumed by servers that are part of a cluster. The queue has no direct contact with clients.

Hope this helps!